# Easiest way to short 50 pairs of wires together

Tags: arduino, switches, relay

I have a serial keyboard that has 24 pins and works via one of the top 11 pins shorting to one of the bottom 13 pins when you press a button (top and bottom membranes touch) and this is picked up by an interface board. I would like to simulate this with an Arduino. There are potentially 143 different combinations but I only need to simulate 50. Normally I would use a relay to act as a switch (i.e. pin 1 and 12 are connected to relay, arduino renergizes relay and these pins get connected) but I don't want to buy/connect 50 different relays along with diodes, transistors, etc. to control them. Is there another way to do this?

I have tried shorting both pins to ground and this is not read by the interface board and I have tried just using a regular transistor but since these pins aren't energized the transistor doesn't conduct.

Comment: What kind of keyboard? PS2? USB?

Comment: I'm wondering if it might be easier to skip this entirely and just spoof the signals that the interface board sends to whatever it's interfacing with.

Comment: I actually do have a solution that spoofs the serial signals but I've found if I try to send more than 1 keypress without waiting around 300ms then it might not get registered and I think this will probably let me do this faster, which is my goal

Comment: Normally there is a pullup R to some voltage to detect contact closure

Comment: `if I try to send more than 1 keypress without waiting around 300ms then it might not get registered` .... what happens if you press 4 or more keys per second?

Comment: You could try 4016 analog switches. These will be smaller, cheaper and faster than relays.